# AWS Lightsail allow ssh only for specifc IP Adddress

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have created a ubuntu server in aws lightsail, I wanted to allow ssh from only specific IP, I tried using iptables in server but its not working, Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Lightsail panel and in the instances tab you will se your all instances
[lightsail panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dS15.png)

Open the instance on which you want to apply rule of ip filtering for ssh
After clicking on instance you will see the following image:
[lightsail details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMm1P.png)

Go to networking tab and scroll to firewall section as shown in image
[firewall showing opened incoming ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLLp5.png)

Click on edit icon infront of ssh port and it will show you some options. One of them will be Restrict to IP address as shown below. On choosing the option it will show you field to add ip address.
[firewall options to edit port open state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Lj5.png)

After adding your ip, click save and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via any kind of security groups for Lightsail. Its firewall rules are a basic allow a rule to the world.

I would suggest allowing SSH via Lightsail, and then running

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s X.X.X.X/32 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Replace the X.X.X.X with your IP address to restrict SSH access to only you.

Answer (score 0):

Now in lightsail they have updated, in network tab you can specify IP address address you want to allow, previously there was no option.